# Rewrite $3\ln (x - 5) - 2\ln (x + 4) + 3\ln (x + 5) - 2\ln (x - 4)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[image]The original problem I have says:

> Rewrite $3\ln (x - 5) - 2\ln (x + 4) + 3\ln (x + 5) - 2\ln (x - 4)$ as a single logarithm using the rules for logarithms.

But the answer and explanation both use $\log_8$ and no $\ln$.

I'm having trouble with how they came up with the $\log_8$.  A picture is included below:

[image]

Comment: Find the base?  The base is $e$ because the logs in the expression are $\ln$.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It says $\log_8$ in the answer!

Comment: Then there is needed information missing from this question.  As it's written right now, the answer is $e$.

Comment: Nothing is missing, I wrote more than they gave!

Comment: I see you've modified the question text, which significantly changes the problem.  An answer involving $\log_8$ still doesn't make sense, because if all you're doing is rewriting the given expression as a single logarithm, then there's no reason to change the base.  If the answer key really has $\log_8$ for that exact problem you've written, then the answer key is incorrect.

Comment: Look at the question again. Are you sure the question uses "$\ln$" and not "$\log_8$"? The answer doesn't mention "$\ln$", so I have my doubts. Maybe you just read it too quickly.

Comment: Probably just another typo! I've encountered already!

Comment: The original question is mostly cut off in the picture but there's enough there that I can tell it says $\ln$.  If the bulk of the picture is supposed to be the answer and explanation then yes, it's indeed a typo.

Comment: Now that we have this all cleared up, I have heavily modified the question and will nominate it for reopening.  If it's reopened I'll post the relevant part of my above comment as an answer for convenience and/or the sake of future viewers.

Comment: I don't see *ANY* typo in the book.  The question as written is entirely wrintten with $\log_8$ and not a single natural log mentioned *anywhere*.

Comment: "Now that we have this all cleared up, I have heavily modified the question and will nominate it for reopening. "  What for?  $3\log_b (x - 5) - 2\log_b (x + 4) + 3\log_b (x + 5) - 2\log_b (x - 4) = \log_b \frac{(x-5)^3(x+5)^3}{(x-4)^2(x+4)^2}$ is undisputed and of not of interest or questioned by anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  You can replace each $\ln$ with (the same) logarithm to any base, and the result will be identical except for the base.  In other words, I could replace every $\ln$ with a $\log_8$ in the answer below and it would still be valid.

You start with this expression:

$$3\ln (x - 5) - 2\ln (x + 4) + 3\ln (x + 5) - 2\ln (x - 4)$$

First use the power rule on each term:

$$\ln [(x - 5)^3] - \ln [(x + 4)^2] + \ln [(x + 5)^3] - \ln [(x - 4)^2]$$

Then use the product and quotient rule:

$$\ln\frac{(x-5)^3(x+5)^3}{(x-4)^2(x+4)^2}.$$

Comment: The problem is easy to solve, but I just don't understand the $\log_8$. I added a picture!

Comment: $\log_8 1 = 0$ ...  $\log_8 1/64 = -2$ ... $\log_8 8^{50} = 50$ ...  And so forth ...

Comment: @egreg I'm missing what you're saying.  What's nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rewrite it into one logarithm then, using the power rule on each term of $3\ln (x - 5) - 2\ln (x + 4) + 3\ln (x + 5) - 2\ln (x - 4)$ gives

$$\begin{align*}  \ln (x-5)^3 + \ln (x+5)^3 - (\ln (x+4)^2 + \ln (x-4)^2) & = \ln (x-5)^3(x+5)^3 - \ln (x+4)^2(x-4)^2 \\ & = \ln \frac{((x-5)(x+5))^3}{((x-4)(x+4))^2} \\ & = \ln \frac{(x^2 - 25)^3}{(x^2 - 16)^2} \end{align*}$$

Comment: The problem is easy to solve, but I just don't understand the $\log_8$. I added a picture!

Comment: You can replace the ln with the log to base 8 for the same result.

Comment: How does one get the 8 is my question!

Comment: Everything starts out as 8's, although you're writing it as ln's for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see this got reopened.  Anyway, it appears as though the original question was asked with $\ln$ and the answer key uses $\log_8$ in the solution.  Either the question should have been in terms of $\log_8$ or the solution should have been in terms of $\ln$.  It's an error on the problem and answer's author's part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $3\ln (x - 5) - 2\ln (x + 4) + 3\ln (x + 5) - 2\ln (x - 4) = y$

$e^{3\ln (x - 5) - 2\ln (x + 4) + 3\ln (x + 5) - 2\ln (x - 4)} = e^y$

$\frac{(x-5)^3(x+5)^3}{(x+4)^2(x-4)^2}= e^y$

From which we *could* do the following if we were really weird.

$\log_8 \frac{(x-5)^3(x+5)^3}{(x+4)^2(x-4)^2} = \log_8 e^y = y*\log_8 e$

$y = \frac{\log_8 \frac{(x-5)^3(x+5)^3}{(x+4)^2(x-4)^2}}{\log_8 e}$

$= \ln \frac{(x-5)^3(x+5)^3}{(x+4)^2(x-4)^2}$

Which really makes me think you wrote the question wrong from the very beginning that that the were not $\ln$ in the book but $\log_8$s.

Can you scan the *question* from the book?  Not just the answer?

Comment: I added, the picture of the equation!